# comparison table for emacs regexp and perl compatible regular expression (PCRE)?

Tags: regex, emacs

Is there a nice table or a cheatsheet on the web that compares the sytax of emacs regex and PCRE?

That I have to remember to escape grouping parenthesis and braces and other differences when I'm using emacs regex, it's all confusing, a syntax comparison table would be good for minimizing confusion.

Answer (score 27):

I will collect syntax differences that I know here. This answer is community wiki, add more if anyone wishes. Always check the preview before adding more.

### When to escape ( ) { } |

In Emacs regexp, (, ), {, }, | are literal and escaped ones (\(, \), \{, \}, \|) are meta.

In Perl-compatible regexp, (, ), {, }, | are meta, and escaped ones are literal.

### * and +

\* is the literal star in both Emacs and Perl. If an expression starts with a star, the starting star is literal in Emacs regexp, illegal in Perl regexp.

Similarly for the plus.

### Character classes

The character classes `\d` (for digits), `\w` (for words), `\s` (for whitespace characters) do not work in Emacs regular expressions, but work in Perl. In Emacs, use `[[:digit:]]`, `[[:word:]]`, `[[:space:]]` instead (with double brackets). In Perl, they are also `[:digit:]`, `[:word:]`, `[:space:]` (single brackets).

`\w` in Emacs matches `'` and `"` too, unlike Perl. This is because text-mode syntax table has `'` and `"` as word characters.

### Backslash constructs

Of backslash constructs mentioned in [Emacs Regexp Backslash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash), the following constructs are NOT in Perl compatible regular expressions.

```
\` \' \= \< \> \_< \_> \sC \cC
```

See also [what < and > can do that \b cannot do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844131/emacs-regular-expression-what-and-can-do-that-b-cannot-do)

`\A`, `\Z`, `\z` are NOT in Emacs. In Emacs, use instead:

```
\` or \'
```

### Complications regarding newlines and interactive usage

See the second section in [Text Pattern Matching in Emacs](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_regex.html). It also mentions why `\n` and `\t` don't match newlines and tabs in incremental search forward for regular expression (`C-M-s` or `M-x isearch-forward-regexp`) and what to do.

### Etc

[Emacswiki regular expression](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression)

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Emacs's regexes are "GNU ERE" in those tables.

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is only on `(){}|` characters isn't it?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I mean, are look-aheads permitted? Obviously escaping differences are in place and it would be good to describe those.

Comment: Ah You are right, for functional difference, you really need comparison charts, I don't have anything right now, I just mentioned the syntax different.

Comment: They are different also in the star character.