# Emacs regular expression: what \< and \> can do that \b cannot do?

Tags: regex, emacs, cpu-word

[Regexp Backslash - GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) says that `\<` matches at the beginning of a word, `\>` matches at the end of a word, and `\b` matches a word boundary. `\b` is just as in other non-Emacs regular expressions. But it seems that `\<` and `\>` are particular to Emacs regular expressions. Are there cases where `\<` and `\>` are needed instead of `\b`? For instance, `\bword\b` would match the same as `\<word\>` would, and the only difference is that the latter is more readable.

Comment: They’re also in GNU Grep and in Vim.

Comment: `\<` and `\>` are from the original *vi*, and remain there to this day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get unexpected results if you assume they behave the same..
What can \< and > that \b can do?
The answer is that `\<` and`\>` are **explicit**... This end of a word! and only this end!
`\b`is **general**.... Either end of a word will match...

GNU Operators * [Word Operators](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/regex/regex.html#SEC26)

```
line="cat dog sky"  
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\b\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\>\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\<\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo
line="cat  dog  sky"  
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\b\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\>\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\<\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo
line="cat  dog  sky  "  
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\b\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\>\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo "$line" |sed -n "s/\(.*\)\<\(.*\)/# |\1|\2|/p"
echo
```

output

```
# |cat dog |sky|
# |cat dog| sky|
# |cat dog |sky|

# |cat  dog  |sky|
# |cat  dog|  sky|
# |cat  dog  |sky|

# |cat  dog  sky|  |
# |cat  dog  sky|  |
# |cat  dog  |sky  |
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like `\<.*?\>` would match only series of word characters, while `\b.*?\b` would match either series of word characters or a series non-word characters, since it can also accept the end of a word, and *then* the beginning of one. If you force the expression between the two to be a word, they do indeed act the same.

Of course, you could replicate the behavior of `\<` and `\>` with `\b\w` and `\w\b`. So I guess the answer is that yes, it's mostly for readability. Then again, isn't that what most escape characters in regular expression are for?

Comment: The Escape char `\\` is never for readability. It is used to differentiate a *regex operator* from a *literal* character of the same glyph

Comment: @fred - What I meant was that the escaped characters such as `\w` and `\d` (not `\ ` itself) can usually be replaced with other characters of a character class, like `[0-9]`.

Comment: Daniel: `\<.*\>` will match any string bounded by word characters. The `.*` is greedy, so matches as many arbitrary characters as possible. To match only individual words, you could use a non-greedy variant: `\<.*?\>`