# please explain this regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

```
  ^[[:space:]]*@
```

I can't figure out what the `[[:space:]]*` means in the above regular expression. Please help, thanks!

Comment: is `space` literally a space or just the word?

Comment: It is the word. I saw this regex from other people's code, but cannot understand it.

Comment: @mclaassen That is not related. This is a POSIX character class, supported by Perl in order to allow regex writers to better conform to Unicode.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1968223/1890567 its just a character class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a POSIX character class, in this case a Unicode-friendly way of representing "any whitespace character".

See [this page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes), scroll down to "POSIX Character Classes".

Comment: POSIX predates Unicode by a large margin. The rationale for abstract character classes (my ad-hoc term, don't remember the official terminology) was more generally related to portability across locales and character sets.

Answer (score 9):

`[:space:]` is a `POSIX character class` which matches `All whitespace characters, including line breaks` in the word.

In other words `[:space:]` is identical to `\s` (since Perl 5.18<sup>[1]</sup>)

http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

---

1. Before 5.18, the vertical tab (U+000B) wasn't included in `\s`.

   ```
   $ diff -u <( unichars -au '\s' ) <( unichars -au '[[:space:]]' ) \
       && echo 'no difference'
   --- /dev/fd/63  2013-05-21 22:08:03.000000000 -0400
   +++ /dev/fd/62  2013-05-21 22:08:03.000000000 -0400
   @@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
     ---- U+00009 CHARACTER TABULATION
     ---- U+0000A LINE FEED (LF)
   + ---- U+0000B LINE TABULATION
     ---- U+0000C FORM FEED (FF)
     ---- U+0000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
     ---- U+00020 SPACE
   ```

Comment: `\s` also doesn't always match U+00A0, the non-breaking space. `/u` makes sure it does. `/a` makes sure it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of expressing things like "whitespace character", and this is one of them. The set `[...]` allows the inclusion of things like `[:space:]` to add space characters to the set.

This reads as:

```
^ # At the beginning of string...
[[:space:]]* # ...zero or more whitespace characters...
@ # ...followed by an at sign.
```

Comment: Not space characters, *whitespace* characters.  Maybe that's what you meant, but accurate terminology is more important than usual in this case, because many regex beginners start out believing that `\s` and/or `[[:space:]]` *do* match only the space character (`U+0020`).

Comment: Whitespace is a better term, adjusted accordingly.