# emacs: regexp matching to extract number from a string

Tags: regex, emacs

I am trying to match only the numbers after the following strings:

```
sequentialGrid: 650274
parallelGrid: 650274
```

My goal is to highlight the numbers, via `M-x highlight-regexp` after lines beginning with `sequentialGrid:` and `parallelGrid:`

Here was my attempt, using a Perl-like approach:

```
^sequentialGrid: \([0-9]*\).*/$1/
```

Unfortunately, Emacs does not support Perl functionality. Thus, I hope my request is not impossible or perhaps someone can offer a convenient workaround.

BTW I verified that `^sequentialGrid: \([0-9]*\).*`  highlights the entire line. I just need to extract the number.

Comment: Never used emacs, but to do what you've described, use a positive lookbehind: e.g ``(?<=sequentialGrid:\s)[0-9]+`` will only match the number

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think emacs' regexp lacks some of these features. I wonder if there is a workaround without sacrificing convenience?

Comment: Oh....can you use a non-capturing group like ``(?:sequentialGrid:\s)[0-9]+`` ?

Comment: Sorry, put the number bit in brackets as well to capture that group: 
``(?:sequentialGrid:\s)([0-9]+)``

Comment: Still doesn't work. I found [this useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946352/comparison-table-for-emacs-regexp-and-perl-compatible-regular-expression-pcre) for using Perl with emacs, but emacs does not support PCRE as far as I know. I still hope to find an easy solution, if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to add font-lock highlighting, the following expression will work:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 
 nil
 '(("^\\(parallel\\|sequential\\)Grid:\\s-*\\([0-9]+\\)"
    2 font-lock-warning-face)))
```

The `nil` MODE parameter in it to the current buffer, or you could specify the mode name as a symbol.  See the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customizing-Keywords.html) and the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords) for more on `font-lock-add-keywords` and `font-lock-remove-keywords`.