# perl-style regular expressions in emacs

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to use perl-style regular expressions in Emacs? I use `regexp-builder` and `query-replace-regexp` pretty often but the Emacs-style regexes throw me off sometimes.

Answer (score 15):

After a bit more searching I found a few similar questions:

- [Is it possible to change emacs' regexp syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879011/is-it-possible-to-change-emacs-regexp-syntax?lq=1)
- [Elisp mechanism for converting PCRE regexps to emacs regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118183/elisp-mechanism-for-converting-pcre-regexps-to-emacs-regexps?rq=1)

It looks like the solutions is to write an elisp function to convert PCRE's to Emacs-style regexes. [This code on GitHub](https://github.com/joddie/pcre2el) looks like a pretty good option.

Comment: That `pcre2el` package you linked is now easy to install and use from Melpa. Just M-x `pcre-query-replace-regexp`. Sweet :)